# Is there any way to check if kafka is up and running from kafka-net

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka-net client to send messages to kafka. I'm just wondering if there is any way to check is kafka server up and can receive messages. I shut kafka down, but the producer has been created successfully and SendMessageAsync just freezes for quite a long time. I've tried to pass timeout but it doesn't change anything. I use kafka-net 0.9
It works just fine when kafka server is up and running

Comment: What is kafka-net? I've used Kafka for the past year and never heard of that term.

Comment: This is actually kafka consumer & producer implementation for .net https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net

Comment: refer to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920923/how-to-check-whether-kafka-server-is-running/49170778#49170778

Answer (score 1):

Broker's id is registered in zookeeper(`/brokers/ids/[brokerId]`) as ephemeral node, which allow other brokers and consumers to detect failures.(Right now the definition of health is fairly naive., if registered in zk `/brokers/ids/[brokerId]` the broker is healthy, otherwise it is dead).

> zookeeper ephemeral node exists as long as the broker's session is
>   active.

You could check if broker is up via ZkUtils.getSortedBrokerList(zkClient), which return all active broker id under `/brokers/ids`

```
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient;

ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(properties.getProperty("zkQuorum"), zkSessionTimeout, zkConnectionTimeout,ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
ZkUtils.getSortedBrokerList(zkClient);
```

**Reference**
[Kafka data structures in Zookeeper](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your constructor, put

```
options = new KafkaOptions(uri);
var endpoint = new DefaultKafkaConnectionFactory().Resolve(options.KafkaServerUri.First(), options.Log);
client = new KafkaTcpSocket(new DefaultTraceLog(), endpoint);
```

and then before you send each message,

```
// test if the broker is alive
var request = new MetadataRequest { Topics = new List<string>() { Topic } };
var task1 = client.WriteAsync(request.Encode()).ConfigureAwait(false);
Task<KafkaDataPayload> task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  task1.GetAwaiter().GetResult());
if (task2.Wait(30000) == false)
{
    throw new TimeoutException("Timeout while sending message to kafka broker!");
}
```

If you have a high volume of messages, this is going to be a performance hit, but with a low volume of messages it shouldn't matter.