# How Do I Kill a Spring Boot Application If Kafka is Unavailable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm running some tests for my spring boot app where if the Kafka/zookeepers are not available (as in not resolvable on the network)

I've noticed that currently, the `StreamsKafkaClient` just continues to retry it's connection to the unavailable servers, but never actually kills the start-up of the application.

How can I terminate the application if Kafka is unavailable?

Comment: I suppose you can kill the spring boot process by process id (in unix env)? Is that not working ? Please add some details about your env.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. When a spring boot application is starting up it will attempt to connect to the kafka stack, but eventhough it throws a `java.net.ConnectException` it doesn't actually kill the application. It just continues to try to connect.

Comment: When I started to work with Kafka I had the same problem, even though I was not using Spring Boot I think you can follow the same approach. You can try simple things first before starting to consume the data, for example, ask for the list of topics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016075/check-if-system-is-connected-to-kafka/47476774#47476774.

Comment: how about destroying the application context?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944144/programmatically-shut-down-spring-boot-application

Comment: This is may be possible. The problem is `SpringApplication.run` never completes. I can get to some Application Events, but not the context to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your config

```
  factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(true);
```