# Best way to perform Kafka consumer healthcheck.

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, health-monitoring

Let's say I have an application which consumes logs from kafka cluster. I want the application to periodically check for the availability of the cluster and based on that perform certain actions. I thought of a few approaches but was not sure which one is better or what is the best way to do this:

1. Create a *MessageProducer* and *MessageConsumer*. The producer publishes heartbeatTopic to the cluster and the consumer looks for it. The issue that I think for this is, where the application is concerned with only consuming, healthcheck has both producing and consuming part.
2. Create a *MessageConsumer* with a new *groupId* which continuously pools for new messages. This way the monitoring/healthcheck is doing the same thing which the application is supposed to do, which I think is good.
3. Create a *MessageConsumer* which does something different from actually consuming the messages. Something like *listTopics* (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477448/2094963) .

Which of these methods is more preferable and why?

Comment: Have you seen [Confluent Control Center]( https://www.confluent.io/product/control-center/)? This does the kind of healthcheck that you're talking about.

Comment: ^ which requires you to pay for licensing after trial period

Answer (score 1):

Going down a slightly different route here, you could potentially poll zookeeper (znode path - /brokers/ids) for this information by using the [Apache Curator library](https://curator.apache.org/index.html).

Here's an idea that I tried and worked - I used the [Curator's Leader Latch recipe](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/leader-latch.html) for a similar requirement.

You could create an instance of [LeaderLatch](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/recipes/leader/LeaderLatch.html) and invoke the [getLeader()](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/recipes/leader/LeaderLatch.html#getLeader--) method. If at every invocation, you get a leader then it is safe to assume that the cluster is up and running otherwise there is something wrong with it.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Adding the zookeeper node path where the leader information is stored.