# check if kafka client producer is running before sending messages in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm using kafka client v 0.8.0 jar file to send kafka messages as producer. But before sending it I want to check if Kafka is up. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to check if kafka is up and running from kafka-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807374/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-kafka-is-up-and-running-from-kafka-net)

Comment: refer to my answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920923/how-to-check-whether-kafka-server-is-running/49170778#49170778](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920923/how-to-check-whether-kafka-server-is-running/49170778#49170778)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if one of your brokers exist in Zookeeper.

> Broker's id is registered in zookeeper(/brokers/ids/[brokerId]) as
>   ephemeral node, which allow other brokers and consumers to detect
>   failures.(Right now the definition of health is fairly naive., if
>   registered in zk /brokers/ids/[brokerId] the broker is healthy,
>   otherwise it is dead).
>
> zookeeper ephemeral node exists as long as the broker's session is
>   active.
>
> You could check if broker is up via
>   ZkUtils.getSortedBrokerList(zkClient), which return all active broker
>   id under /brokers/ids

[see stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807374/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-kafka-is-up-and-running-from-kafka-net)

If you just want to see directly when the broker dies,
set the acks property to 1 or all(-1) or/and max.in.flight.requests.per.connection property to 1.